# UIPanGestureRecognizer stops working when when panned up, not when panned down

Tags: ios, opacity, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm basically creating a screen dimmer here. I've put a black view over the screen and am using a UIPanGestureRecognizer to adjust the opacity based on whether the user scrolls up or down. Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)dimScreen:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //Get translation
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat distance = translation.y;

    //add a fraction of the translation to the alpha
    CGFloat newAlpha = self.blackScreen.alpha + distance/self.view.frame.size.height;
    //check if the alpha is more than 1 or less than 0
        if (newAlpha>1) {
        newAlpha = 1;
        }else if (newAlpha<0.0){
        newAlpha = 0.0;
        }
    self.blackScreen.alpha = newAlpha;
    //reset translation to get incremental change
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
```

If I pan down, the opacity goes to 1.0, and I can still adjust it. If I pan up till the opacity is 0, I can no longer pan at all. The dimScreen: selector stops getting called. Can anyone describe what is causing this issue?

Comment: Show the code when you add the gesturerecognizer.

Comment: Hey Arbitur, the gesturerecognizer is added in the interface builder.

Comment: try adding it by code, I had problems adding gesturerecognizers via interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Views with alpha values of 0 no longer receive touches. In fact, it seems that below 0.011 alpha the view stops receiving touches. So, your code can be made to work by changing the values in your else-if statement:

```
if (newAlpha>1) {
        newAlpha = 1;
    }else if (newAlpha <= 0.011){
        newAlpha = 0.011;
    }
```

I've seen other people mention a value of 0.02 instead of 0.011 which I found empirically. I don't know how "safe" it is to assume that either of these numbers is fixed and will continue to work in the future, but it seems to work for now.